# select query using an invalid package reference in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a package that contains a function which simply returns a description from a table given the product id.

now i have a procedure that has a select statement which makes the use of this function.
this morning i noticed that, the package body has become invalid, 
and all the calls to this procedure results in running that select statement,
 which never completes because of invalid package reference.

I need to make changes to my package, but i cannot do so until all the processes have completed ( or rolled back).

What can i do..?

Comment: I don't think that you can do *anything* until the package is released, i.e. nobody uses it. Until then, you can make changes you mentioned (in editor), but won't be able to compile it.

Comment: If your package then a became invalid then a dependency it has changed or it itself was changed. Either way Oracle will automatically attempt to recompile it, and  if anything else is using it that recompile will wait.  If that fails it returns the error "ORA-06575: Package or function _<name>_ is in an invalid state", and terminates the  statement/procedure immediately - unless you trap and discard the error. (i.e when others then ).  So your other procedure is waiting that recompile or has improper error handling.

Comment: *"What can i do..?"* Besides waiting for your processes to finish? Get a DBA to kill the sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query active processes using the following query to obtain the sid & serial#.

```
SELECT ses.sid, ses.serial#, ses.username, ses.schemaname, sql.sql_text
FROM   v$session ses,
       v$sql     sql
WHERE  sql.sql_id(+) = ses.sql_id
AND    ses.type      = 'USER'
AND    ses.status    = 'ACTIVE'
AND    UPPER(sql.sql_text) LIKE '%MY_PKG.MY_FUNC%';
```

Then you can have a DBA terminate the sessions executing your function.

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '<sid, serial#>';
```